# What happened to ScholarlyHub?

Tags: online-publication, open-access, projects, networking

Does anyone have an update on the status of the launch of the open-access research-social-network [ScholarlyHub](https://www.scholarlyhub.org)?
Is this still an ongoing project or did they quit?

There was much coverage after their launch in 2017, but since 2018 there is not much news about it and their website & Twitter is not really maintained anymore, so it is not clear to me if we can count on this project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all practical purposes, any plans for a real website are pretty much dead, unless some rich donor suddenly shows up out of nowhere. For the foreseeable future, the people behind ScholarlyHub are mostly focusing their energies on advocating for open access initiatives in general.

If you need a Humanities-focused alternative to ScholarlyHub, try [Humanities Commons](https://hcommons.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Where did you find out about this? This site sound like a really good idea, I would like to keep up to date regarding it's status.

Comment: I was one of the original donors in 2017, and for about a year or so, I did my best to keep up to date with news from the team. It is unfortunate that the plan has not advanced, but that's life. As for keeping up to date, it might be best to contact the Twitter account of Prof. Jeroen Bosman. https://twitter.com/jeroenbosman